# Invalid Host Header when ngrok tries to connect to React dev server

Tags: reactjs, localhost, ngrok

I'm trying to test my React application on a mobile device. I'm using ngrok to make my local server available to other devices and have gotten this working with a variety of other applications. However, when I try to connect ngrok to the React dev server, I get the error:

```
Invalid Host Header
```

I believe that React blocks all requests from another source by default. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1000, accepted):

I'm encountering a similar issue and found two solutions that work as far as viewing the application directly in a browser

```
ngrok http 8080 --host-header="localhost:8080"
ngrok http --host-header=rewrite 8080
```

obviously, replace 8080 with whatever port you're running on

this solution still raises an error when I use this in an embedded page, that pulls the bundle.js from the react app. I think since it rewrites the header to localhost when this is embedded, it's looking to localhost, which the app is no longer running on

Comment: the first one was enough

Comment: In case someone else runs into this problem: This works, but it seems to mess up cookies, meaning it breaks login mechanisms and such!

Comment: This problem was also for Angular 6, and it works, thanks

Comment: The `-host-header` should come before the port number, so the first example should be `ngrok http -host-header="localhost:8080"  8080`

Comment: ./ngrok http --host-header=rewrite 8080

Comment: @pdowling I'm having this issue. Is there a way to not break the login functionality? I'm currently try to build login/logout functionality to facebook with my app and it works sometimes but not all, and I don't know if it's my code or ngrok https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59522085/facebook-sdk-login-logout-ngrok

Comment: @adam.k does using the https version of the forwarding URL solves the problem?

Comment: you deserve a beer :)

Comment: FYI, you can achieve the same thing using Cloudflare Tunnels (a free ngrok alternative) via this command `cloudflared tunnel --url http://localhost:8080 --http-host-header localhost:8080`. More details: [Cloudflare Quick Tunnels](https://gist.github.com/randyburden/cbda4da88bc4e6cd9e17d59ecf03dcf9)

Comment: The first one worked for me as well, with a local Angular application listening on port 4200

Answer (score 40):

**Option 1**

If you do not need to use Authentication you can add configs to ngrok commands

> ngrok http 9000 --host-header=rewrite

or

> ngrok http 9000 --host-header="localhost:9000"

But in this case Authentication will not work on your website because ngrok rewriting headers and session is not valid for your ngrok domain

**Option 2**

If you are using webpack you can add the following configuration

```
devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true
}
```

In that case Authentication header will be valid for your ngrok domain

Comment: Note that in Webpack 5, `disableHostCheck` no longer seems to exist as a valid key for `devServer`.

Instead you should use [`allowedHosts`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverallowedhosts):

`allowedHosts: ['your.hostname.com']`,  or more dangerously `allowedHosts: 'all'`

Answer (score 24):

Don't know why but tried everything and it didn't work for me.
What finally worked for me is this:
`ngrok http https://localhost:4200 --host-header="localhost:4200"`

it might be useful for someone

Comment: i needed double dash in --host `ngrok http https://localhost:4200 --host-header="localhost:4200"`

Comment: @tq fixed the typo in the answer

Answer (score 7):

If you use webpack devServer the simplest way is to set disableHostCheck, check [webpack doc](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverdisablehostcheck) like this

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
    compress: true,
    host: 'localhost',
    // host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 8080,
    disableHostCheck: true //for ngrok
},
```

Answer (score 2):

I used this set up in a react app that works. I created a config file named configstrp.js that contains the following:

```
module.exports = {
ngrok: {
// use the local frontend port to connect
enabled: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
subdomain: process.env.NGROK_SUBDOMAIN,
authtoken: process.env.NGROK_AUTHTOKEN
},   }
```

Require the file in the server.

```
const configstrp      = require('./config/configstrp.js');
const ngrok = configstrp.ngrok.enabled ? require('ngrok') : null;
```

and connect as such

```
if (ngrok) {
console.log('If nGronk')
ngrok.connect(
    {
    addr: configstrp.ngrok.port,
    subdomain: configstrp.ngrok.subdomain,
    authtoken: configstrp.ngrok.authtoken,
    host_header:3000
  },
  (err, url) => {
    if (err) {

    } else {

    }
   }
  );
 }
```

Do not pass a subdomain if you do not have a custom domain

Answer (score 1):

### Windows, ngrok v3

```
ngrok http <url> --host-header=<host>:<port>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I am attaching a error image which i was facing but after a google and documentation search, i found the exact solution.

```
ngrok http 4200 --host-header="localhost:4200"
```

**NOTE** : I was working on angular that's why I used 4200 port, but you can select a port as per your requirement.

#angular #ngrok #localhost